# Custom Lightning Component internal state

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to create own custom checkbox component with SLDS styles (as standard ui:checkbox not compatible with SLDS) but do not quite understand how can save internal state in the component.
E.g. I would like to place several custom checkboxes in another component and based on the selected checkboxes do some logic.
How can I achieve this? Is this approach suitable for Lightning Framework or do I need to handle state of the inner components through events?

Comment: How is ui:checkbox not compatible with SLDS? Are you certain? I"ve not tried, but looking at it, it seems you could simply put a ui:inputCheckbox inside the decoration of SLDS and it might work.

Comment: If I were rebuilding ui:inputCheckbox, I would start with the way it is built in the open source project: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputCheckbox . I would pay special attention to the fact that it extends ui:input and implements an interface.

Comment: In the SLDS Docs there is a statement regarding the checkboxes _The ability to style checkboxes with CSS varies across browsers. To ensure that checkboxes look the same everywhere, we use a custom DOM. Pay close attention to the markup, because all elements must exist for the styles to work._ [SLDS Checkbox](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms#checkbox)
And the ui:checkbox generates different html code [ui:checkbox](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?descriptor=ui:inputCheckbox&defType=component)